# How do I make it so that one section goes over another section upon scroll (similar to Google Ads site at the bottom) w/o any libraries?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, css-animations

If you go to https://ads.google.com, you will see at the end that their CTA section goes over the prior site. I want to do that without using any other libraries. Is there a way to do that purely in CSS? If not, is there a simple JS script that would do that for me?

Comment: Try `position: sticky` on bottom layer, `z-index: ...` on top layer.

Comment: It's not like that, it's one section that goes over the entire website. What would i apply position:sticky to then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: sticky` on `.slide-under`

`z-index: 10;` on `.slide-over`

```css
.a {
  --bg: gray;
}

.b {
  --bg: navy;
}

.c {
  --bg: brown;
}

.d {
  --bg: white;
}

.container>div,
.slide-under>div,
.slide-over>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

.slide-under {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.slide-over {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
<div class="slide-under">
  <div class="b">
    some text......
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide-over">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, but like in the Google Ads site, how do they make it fade to white?

Comment: That has to use javascript (`addEventListener('scroll', ...)`) to detect the loacation of `.slide-over` in window, then set the opacity of `.slide-under`.